# Spring how to limit requests by ip from exact controller

Tags: java, spring, controller, ip, limit

Is there any easy way to limit the requests from an exact `Spring RESTful controller` by `IP address`? For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/create",method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

I would like to let the client create around 3 users per day.
Should I create the database table where I keep the IPs and counters and delete the data from the table every day? Is there a better way?

Comment: Instead of deleting the row keep the counter and the start day and then calculate how many users have been created from the start day till current day and make sure it is not (count of users)/(days passed from start day) >= 3.

Comment: I like your idea, but what happens if the client does't create users for a weak :) than he can create like 20 in one day. That's a bad limitation in my case :)

Comment: Ok, I see how are your requirements. In that case you can check if current day is different than the day count was updated for and reset the count to 1, otherwise increment if it is not 3 yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. every ip can invoke this api up to 3 times(it is constant) at specific time and then after 24 hours the limit is reset?
2. or in 0:00 the limit is reset and if the limit is configuable?

In the former case, it is recommended that using limit rate limiting library such as bucket4j to fit this scenario(you can choose some cache as its backend) and set limit to this interface via declare config in config file.(https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bucket4j)

Int the latter case, it's maybe to design your table to persist the config and use org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor to interceptor the request or put the check code under the @RequestMapping method.